# A dataset with some very, very poor X variables - distribution and outliers

Tags: distributions, data-transformation, outliers

I have been handed a dataset with many poor variables and what appear to be outliers.

Looking at histograms and box plots of the distributions, many cannot even form a box plot due to the distribution.
Some of the distributions are just plain terrible with a chunk of single numbers and a second chunk of single numbers with an arbitrary gap.

Nonreal example, variable x1, 500 entries =

```
50 entries with value 45,
200 entries with value 200, 
250 variables with value 400.
```

Note that these may well be genuine.

Others have dramatic outliers beyond an otherwise normal distribution.

One problem is that I cannot legitimately exclude the outliers (if justified I would absolutely remove them) as I do not (and cannot) find their cause—but I feel I will have to remove most anyway.
Also, I can only remove the outlier, not the whole row, otherwise my data set will have very, very few members—is this acceptable?

Comment: I would like to add that a fair few variables have a large genuine 0 population, followed by a smaller non zero single value population.

Comment: What are you trying to find out? Are you after some sort of regression model? If so, is one of your "bad" variables the dependent variable?

Comment: Does 'X variable' mean anything in particular?

Comment: Yes i am trying to linear/nonlinear model a normally distributed variable (the output variable in question is fine, no bad outliers and nicely distributed) - No, X variable is just to indicate one of many input variables

Comment: @Samuel: You seem to be under the impression that a normal distribution of predictor variables is a necessary assumption for regression models: it isn't; the response is modelled conditional on their observed values. Just watch out for observations that have an especially high influence on the coefficient estimates owing to their positions in predictor space.

Comment: By the way, you can add extra information by editing your question; it's often helpful to do so rather than appending it to a growing comment thread.